# Apple Preview resets notes and highlighting on a PDF. How do I recover them?

Tags: time-machine, pdf, preview, macos, file-recovery

I ended up having exactly the problem described [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8319420): I was highlighting and taking notes on a PDF file with macOS 10.14 Apple Preview and I realised only yesterday after finishing studying a university pdf that the last version of the file has only saved the highlighting of the last chapter of the pdf.

The thing is that in Time Machine previous file saves actually do have previous notes and highlighting, it is just that every file save only has a portion of around 50~70 pages of saved edits, while previous edits disappear and the file looks like as if I started highlighting from page 50, and then from page 100 and so on...

I could theorically save duplicates of each edited version and then remove “cleaned up” pages to recover with the ones from a previously saved version, but my philosophy is that we use computers to help us, not to help the computer, is there any way to do that edit-recovery automatically?

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening again? It’s the first time I can’t trust preview to save my notes.